# pegar dados json imprimir php

Tags: php

Gente como pego os dados em php de latitude e longitude dessa url abaixo

```
https://api.findmespot.com/spot-main-web/consumer/rest-api/2.0/public/feed/0ozWRQqxiMnv5bqJzSUIMyUIIbMGrP5qu/message.json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar a função `file_get_contents()`. Ficaria algo como:

```
$conteudo = file_get_contents('https://api.findmespot.com/spot-main-web/consumer/rest-api/2.0/public/feed/0ozWRQqxiMnv5bqJzSUIMyUIIbMGrP5qu/message.json');
echo $conteudo;
```

Como é um JSON, podemos transformar ele em um objeto usando a função `json_decode($conteudo)`. Se quiser ver o formato exato do JSON você pode usar o seguinte código

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($conteudo);
echo '</pre>';
```

Agora que você já tem o conteúdo em um objeto, podemos fazer um `foreach` para percorrer todo o conteúdo do JSON

```
foreach ($conteudo->response->feedMessageResponse->messages->message as $key) {
    print_r('Latitude: '.$key->latitude);
    echo ' - ';
    print_r('longitude: '.$key->longitude);
    echo '<br>';
}
```

O código completo ficou assim então:

```
$conteudo = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.findmespot.com/spot-main-web/consumer/rest-api/2.0/public/feed/0ozWRQqxiMnv5bqJzSUIMyUIIbMGrP5qu/message.json'));
foreach ($conteudo->response->feedMessageResponse->messages->message as $key) {
    print_r('Latitude: '.$key->latitude);
    echo ' - ';
    print_r('longitude: '.$key->longitude);
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Phelipe e isso mesmo so nao estou sabendo agora e pegar latitude e longitude  rsrs

Comment: Complementei minha resposta. Agora ele pega os valores que você queria. Basta entender a estrutura do JSON e ir percorrendo ele.

Comment: Perfeito meu amigo

Comment: pode me tirar só mais uma duvida como eu faria para pegar apenas o ultima latitude e longitude ?

Comment: pode me tirar só mais uma duvida como eu faria para pegar apenas o ultima latitude e longitude ?